# Is Kokapetl's dialogue universally bleeped out in the episode "Veils of Rana'Ori"?

Tags: censorship, mysterious-cities-of-gold

In the section "Kokapetl's Scoop" of the episode "Veils of Rana'Ori" (Season 2, episode 23), called "Les Voiles de Rana'Ori"    in French, of Mysterious Cities of Gold (the 2012 series) Kokapetl's dialogue was heavily bleeped out near the end, while showing a cameraman walking in a qanat carrying water:

> Kokapetl: But where does water come from in the desert?
>
> Narrator: Most often the water comes from the Zagros mountains
>
> Kokapetl: Huh that's super far
>
> Narrator: Look at these mounds of dirt. They indicate that underneath
> qanats can be found. Qanats are underground channels and shafts that
> were dug out by man. These tunnels could be several kilometres long
> and carried fresh water all the way to the caravanserai
>
> Kokapetl: [Heavy bleeping] got his dirty-assed feet in it

Is his dialogue just bleeped out in SBS/NITV broadcast, bleeped out in all English translations (not surprising, if it were first broadcast in English by SBS/NITV) or was it designed to be bleeped out even in the original French?

Comment: As it's entirely a kids' show, I'm surprised they even scripted language that would need to be bleeped at all. I can't find season 2 (for free & I'm not paying for it just to answer a question :) but I can access season 1 if you can find something comparable.

Comment: @Tetsujin it’s the only case anything has been bleeped out in any seasons 1-3. I haven’t seen season 4 yet, it was broadcast in Europe in 2020 and apparently hasn’t been broadcast in Australia.

Comment: OK. In that case I can only guess they did it for emphasis & it's bleeped on all versions. It's a kids' show, CeeBeebies in the UK, which is for young children, not even teens. (BTW, IMDB claims only 2 seasons, though no doubt it may have been re-split for broadcast).